# PHP Next & Back buttons instead of pagination

Tags: php, navigation, pagination

I would like to modify the script below so that there are no pagination numbers, just a previous and next button. I would like the previous/next links to show/be grayed out depending on whether the next/previous page exists. For example, if you are on page 1, no previous button would show because page 0 doesn't exist.

The script I'm using at the moment grabs data from a text file - creating dynamic pages - and creates pagination based on that:

(before start of html)

```
$data=file("brief.txt");
$pages=0;
foreach($data as $temp){
    $x=explode("|",$temp);
    if($x[0]>0){
        $pages=$pages+1;
    }
}
if($_GET['p']){
    $page=$_GET['p'];
}
if($_GET['i']){
    $index=$_GET['i'];
}

if($index == "p"){
    $page=$page-1;
}
if($index == "n"){
    $page=$page+1;
}
if($page < 1){
    $page=1;
}
if($page > $pages){
    $page=$pages;
} 
$line=$data[$page-1];
$fields=explode("|",$line);
?>
```

(in body section)

```
 <?php
 $show=6;
 echo "<li><a href='?i=p&p=$page'>&#171; PREV</li></a>";

if($page-($show/2) > 1){
    $temp=$page-$show;
    echo "<li><a href='?p=$temp'>...</li></a>";
}
if($page-($show/2) >= 1 && $page+($show/2) <= $pages){
    $start=$page-($show/2);
    $stop=$page+($show/2);
}
if($page-($show/2) < 1){
    $start=1;
    $stop=$show;
}
if($page+($show/2) > $pages){
    $start=$pages-$show;
    $stop=$pages;
}  
for($i=$start; $i<=$stop; $i++){
    if($page==$i){
        echo "<li class='active'>$i</li></a>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<li><a href='?p=$i'>$i</li></a>";
    }
}
if($page+($show/2) < $pages){
    $temp=$page+$show;
    echo "<li><a href='?p=$temp'>...</li></a>";
}
echo "<li><a href='?i=n&p=$page'>NEXT &#187;</li></a>";
?>
```

I've gotten just the next and previous buttons to show and work from simply changing the script to this:

```
<?php
echo "<li><a href='?i=p&p=$page'>&#171; PREV</li></a>";
echo "<li><a href='?i=n&p=$page'>NEXT &#187;</li></a>";
?>
```

But I don't know where to go from there. Any help would be awesome! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one thing, the nesting of the tags is wrong - </a> should come before </li>. Secondly, the code isn't very elegant - it could be much shorter.

But to answer your question about disabling the links, you could just use

```
<?php
if($page == 1) echo "<li>echo &#171; PREV</li>" else echo "<li><a href='?i=p&p=$page'>&#171; PREV</a></li>";
if($page == $pages) echo "<li>echo NEXT &#187;" else echo "<li><a href='?i=n&p=$page'>NEXT &#187;</a></li>";
?>
```

(your total number of pages can be found in $pages).

Comment: Thanks! :) Although I had some issues with the <li>echo parts, so I changed it to this: if ($page == 1) echo ""; else echo "<li><a href='?i=p&p=$page'>&#171; PREV</li></a>";

Comment: Guess that's fine as well :-)